# BuildBot close public access

Tags: buildbot

By default web interface of BuildBod is a public readable, so anyone can view my builds, etc. I want to close it from guests, so only registered developers will be able to view my BuildBot page.

How can I do it?

I use BuildBot 0.8.9.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Buildbot 0.8.8 and not try to do this, but in Buildbot 0.8.9 [documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#webstatus-configuration-parameters) there seems a "view" options for authorization, probably this is what you want.

Basic implementation could be like this;

```
from buildbot.status.html import WebStatus
from buildbot.status.web.authz import Authz
from buildbot.status.web.auth import BasicAuth


users = [('bob', 'secret-pass'), ('jill', 'super-pass')]
authz = Authz(auth=BasicAuth(users),
    view='auth' # only authenticated users
    ...
)
c['status'].append(WebStatus(http_port=8080, authz=authz))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also move your buildbot machine under vpn, and give access to developer. This way you can hide BuildBot UI completely from outside. This is how it is done in company I work.